# ASP.NET Core Web API controller to extract http header on each request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to extract http header prior to executing any controller action and have it stored in a property on a controller.
The controllers inherit from `ControllerBase` which doesn't have `OnActionExecuting` to override.

I can't seem to find an elegant way of doing it other than having something like `MyCustomBaseController` that implements `ControllerBase`, have all of my controllers implement `MyCustomBaseController` and then do action filter on `MyCustomBaseController` that would extract headers and save it to some custom property on it.

Sounds clumsy.

Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: did you try `middleware`?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk no. is there a way to write header value to controller property from middleware or the best it can do is writing to `httpContext.Items`?

Comment: Is the real question how to bind to a header? Have you checked the [FromHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromheaderattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) attribute?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, the real question is if there is a way to have header value in custom controllers property before any of the actions is being executed.

Comment: @dzg that's your assumed solution to accessing the header value. There's no reason or benefit to binding to properties instead of parameters. Each request is server by a different controller instance, so a *property* can't be used to "communicate" between actions or with views. Unless you use a static property (a bad idea and a security risk), property contents aren't persisted

Comment: [FromHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromheaderattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can be used with properties too and possibly inherited, based on the `System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Parameter | System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=false, Inherited=true)` attribute

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so if i understand correctly, what you're suggesting is reading header directly from `httpContext` within an action where i need the value? (or bind it to parameter, same thing)

Comment: No, I'm saying use normal parameter binding, like you would with query or form parameters. `MyAction(int id,[FromHeader] string myHeader)` or `MyAction(MyDTO dto)`. `AttributeTargets.Property` suggests you can apply the attribute to a *model* property

Comment: Why are you asking about a *controller property* specifically? Controller properties are never used to bind to request data. You'll find over 300 SO questions and answers about FromHeader though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, that make sense. i believe you're right that i went into a dead-end for no practical reason. please post it as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Did you have some other stack in mind, like Razor Pages? The "PageModel" architecture can cause a "bit" of confusion

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, its a rest api. probably old habit of having, for example, `Controller.User` as a property. But you absolutely have a point: there is no reason for having header value as a property and if there is ever a need for communicating between different parts of the pipeline (which is rare), we have `httpContext.Items` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind header contents to action parameters or model properties using the [FromHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromheaderattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) attribute.

Request data isn't bound using controller properties in MVC or Web API, the way it's done in Razor Pages. Data can only be bound to action parameters. You can find the available binding sources in the [Binding Source Parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#binding-source-parameter-inference) section of the Web API overview docs.

In a controller-based aplication (MVC, Web API), a new controller instance is created to server each request. Request data is provided to the action itself, not the controller.